# Java - Use annotations and intercept methods?

Tags: java, android, annotations, interception

Is there a simple way to intercept methods in java. I need to add an annotation to required methods so that a piece of logic gets called before going through the method.

```
public void verifyActivity() {
   // Asset if you are on a wrong page
}

@VerifyActivity
public void testLogin() {
   // Login for my automate test
}

@VerifyActivity
public void testSomethingElse() {
   // Test some other UI Automation stuff
}
```

**EDIT:**

The recommended guice library for android apps does not contain AOP.
Is it possible to achieve this using reflection without adding any libraries?

Comment: Hi @aryaxt, did you find a solution? If you did, can you share? I found a library; https://code.google.com/p/android-method-interceptor/
It is not documented and I can't understand what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guice provides easy way of implementing annotations. Check this out.

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use Guice, and since I am not using it directly on my android app, there shouldn't be any performance problem.

Answer (score 2):

As sid malani said [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) is great for this. In general you want to read up on [aspect oriented programming tutorials](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/AW/Tutorials) ... There is a nice tool called [JMangler](http://roots.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/tailor/jmangler) that may be of use as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection if you've coded to interfaces through [dynamic proxies.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it can be nicely done without any 3rd party libs.

There is a library called cglib, which is capable of such things.

Basically it will create a subclass of the intercepted class at runtime. You'll be able to "override" methods by implementing an InvocationHandler, which will act as a proxy when any of the superclass methods being called.